# Orthonormal Basis and Matrix of a Linear Operator Proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B = $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for Rn
Let p = $[v_1, \dots, v_n$].
Prove that for any x, we have that the B-matrix of x is equal to the tranpose of P times x.

I am unsure as to how to begin this proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you call "B-matrix of x", but I will assume that you are looking for the components of $x$ in the basis $B$.  In other words, you are looking for numbers $b_i$ such that
$$x = b_1\nu_1+\cdots+b_n\nu_n.$$

Since $B$ is orthonormal, for any $i$ and $j$, we have
$$\nu_i^T\nu_j=\delta_{ij}.$$

Therefore,when you multiply $\nu^T_i$ by $x$ only $i$-th term in the sum survives and we get
$$\nu_i^Tx=b_i$$

or

$$P^Tx=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}^T.$$